# how to update multiple select row in db2

Tags: sql, select, db2

i have problem to update the multiple selection row in table.This is my query.
Anyone know what the problem?.

```
--update mvp_employer--
set (MEI_EMP_CAT_CD) = 
(select case when a.MEI_EMP_CAT_CD is not null then a.MEI_EMP_CAT_CD else b.MEI_EMP_CAT_CD end MEI_EMP_CAT_CD
from (
select MEI_ROC_NO,MEI_DOC_TYP_CD,MEI_EMP_CAT_CD from jimd2.mvp_employer
where mei_roc_no in (select mei_roc_no from MVP_EMPLOYER
WHERE MEI_DOC_TYP_CD IN ('632','999')
group by mei_roc_no having count(*) >1)
and MEI_DOC_TYP_CD IN ('632')
order by mei_roc_no, mei_doc_typ_cd ) a
FULL JOIN
(
select MEI_ROC_NO,MEI_DOC_TYP_CD,MEI_EMP_CAT_CD from jimd2.mvp_employer
where mei_roc_no in (select mei_roc_no from MVP_EMPLOYER
WHERE MEI_DOC_TYP_CD IN ('632','999')
group by mei_roc_no having count(*) >1)
and MEI_DOC_TYP_CD ='999'
order by mei_roc_no, mei_doc_typ_cd ) b 
on a.mei_roc_no = b.mei_roc_no
) 
where  MEI_DOC_TYP_CD IN ('632') 
and mei_roc_no ='AS0002107-A'
```

ERROR:-
Error code -811, SQL state 21000: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-811, SQLSTATE=21000, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=3.53.95

Comment: Can you execute the SELECT's standalone? (All versions, i.e. sub-queries and complete.)

Comment: *MEI_EMP_CAT_CD
PS
PS
PS
PS
PS
PS*
This is my result.it return many row

Answer (score 0):

You should probably read the error message:

[SQL0811N   The result of a scalar fullselect, SELECT INTO statement, or VALUES INTO statement is more than one row](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql00811n.html)

So your query returns more rows and DB2 does not know which one to assign to your set clause. 
Correct your query - maybe add a distinct (depends on your needs) - and try again

Comment: Tq for youe help. yes.correct. my result display many row.But the actually,I really want to update all row once time.do you have any idea?

Comment: If you want to update multiple rows with each individual values returned from a sub-query -  search for correlated subqueries in updates.